# Script for monitoring RAID status

Tags: raspbian, monitoring, raid

I am looking for help with the creation of a script to monitor the status of a RAID implemented using mdadm.

Is it possible to create is an icon that can be clicked on, script starts up and displays the current RAID status in a window, which refreshes every however often? And if so, how?

Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just pointing me towards a good guide to creating it or a better understanding.

Thanks.

Comment: which scripting language will the script be written in?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would be easier to write a bash shell script or do something with Python. In terms of scripting or any code writing, I'm an absolute novice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a script for this, you can just use the `watch` command.

```
watch cat /proc/mdstat
```

Options you may want to use:

> -d, --differences [permanent]
> Highlight the differences between successive updates.  Option will read optional argument that changes highlight to be permanent, allowing to see what has changed at least once since first iteration.
>
> -n, --interval seconds
> Specify update interval.  The command will not allow quicker than 0.1 second interval, in which the smaller values are converted. Both '.' and ',' work for any locales.

Comment: Thanks for that, I wasn't aware of that command.
The need for a script for a way to view it is for other people, a sort of user-friendly option for those that don't know Linux or even computing all that well.

Comment: If you just want alerts when something is wrong, you may want to use `mdadm --monitor`.

Comment: Yes I know, what I'm after isn't the commands used to monitor or look at the RAID status. I'm more after a way to produce a script that will pull that information out with some sort of variable, etc.